# Capital G + showing instead of g+ when I using font awesome css

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am using below code to get the Google + social media link with font awesome css,

```
 <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
```

Problem here is I am trying to get the small g+ icon but I am getting is Capital G+ icon.

Can some one suggest me on it?

Thanks,
Naresh.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a small g google plus icon using [font awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/).

Comment: "g+" is not part of the font awesome set of icons.

Comment: use `<i class="icon-google-plus-sign"></i>` or `<i class="icon-google-plus"></i>`

Answer (score 1):

use this class for small g+ icon class="icon-google-plus"

Comment: Thanks for your answers, When I use all above options there is no image renders.

Answer (score 0):

Use font awesome cdn version 4.4.0 or earlier.

For example: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css